# use sessions in web service

Tags: web-services, session, asp.net-mvc-5

i am creating a web app in mvc5 in which i am passing my login information through session in web service

```
        if (pm != null)
        {
            string pm1 = pm.ToString();
            HttpContext.Current.Session["pm"] = pm1.ToString();
        }
```

here if my `string pm` is `not null` then the value of string pm will be stored in my session, but i am getting the error when i run my web service

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.

any other ways to do this?

Comment: From where you are saving data into session ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this you need to enable session in webmethod attribute
and then use

```
    String.IsNullOREmpty(pm)

  [webmethod(EnableSession = true)]
   public string  your method name
   {
      if (pm != null)
    {
        string pm1 = pm.ToString();
        HttpContext.Current.Session["pm"] = pm1.ToString();
    }

    }
```